# How do I form a new object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

So my task is to create a function that takes the first value and make it the new key in my new obj and the second value and keep it as a key still I know i have to iterate through the array and refer to each value with the dot notation but when i try to assign the value to be a key it gives me an err i know its because its evaluated as a string but there must be some easier way of this here is the code

```
var people = [ {name: "Anthony", score: 10},
{name: "Fred", score : 10},
{name: "Anthony", score: -8},
{name: "Winnie", score: 12}];

function countScores(people) {
  var obj = people[0]
  var key = obj.name
  var value = obj.score

}
countScores(people)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var people = [
  {name: "Anthony", score: 10},
  {name: "Fred",   score: 10},
  {name: "Anthony", score: -8},
  {name: "Winnie",  score: 12}
];

function countScores(people) {
  var target = {};
  
  for (var i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    var obj = people[i];
    target[obj.name] = obj.score;
  }
  
  return target;
}

console.log(countScores(people));
```

Comment: I get the jist but how does setting target[obj.name] = obj.score create the new obj?